# Django 'getattr(row,', expected 'empty' or 'endfor''

Tags: python, django

**Code I'm working with:**

```
{% for row in all_rows %}
    <tr>
      {% for names in all_fields_names %}
        <td> {% getattr(row, names) %} </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I get error:

> 'getattr(row,', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'

I've tried:

```
 {% for row, names in (all_rows, all_fields_names) %}
    <tr>
        <td> {% getattr(row, names) %} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

With no success. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more elaborative, as in what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

You can't call functions like that inside the template. You'd want to create a custom template tag.

Custom Template Tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def getattr(row, field_name, default=None):
  return getattr(row, field_name, default)
```

Call it inside your template like so:

```
{% for row, names in (all_rows, all_fields_names) %}
    <tr>
        <td> {% getattr row names %} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```